# Simple functions converge to $f$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> I wanted to prove (or disprove) the fact that if a sequence of simple functions $\Phi_n\rightarrow f $ almost everwhere, then $f$ is measurable.

We know that $g=\limsup \Phi_n$ is a measurable funtion and $f$ and $g$ only disagree in a set of measure zero given by $N$. Therefore, we have:

$$f^{-1}(a,\infty)=(f^{-1}(a,\infty)\cap N) \dot{\cup } (f^{-1}(a,\infty)\cap N^C)=(f^{-1}(a,\infty)\cap N) \dot{\cup } (g^{-1}(a,\infty)\cap N^C)$$

If $\mu$ our measure is complete and because $f^{-1}(a,\infty)\cap N\subset N$ we are done and $f$ will be measurable.

I have two questions:

1. Is this still true if our measure is not complete?

For general functions, I think this is not true, but I haven't used the fact that $\Phi_n$ are simple functions, so maybe there is another proof which does't rely on completeness.

EDIT: It isn't true, as Anne Bauval cleverly remarked.

2. Is this true for the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$?

By Caratheodory's Theorem, the outer measure $l^*$ of the pre-measure $l$ (defined in the algebra used to construct the lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$) is complete in $l^*$ measurable sets ($M^*$). When we consider the sigma algebra generated by $A$, $\sigma(A)\subset M^*$ we could loose completeness. Is $l^*|_{\sigma(A)}$ complete in the case of the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: 1) These 2 distinct questions should be 2 distinct posts. 2) What is $A$ in your second question? 3) For a counterexample to your first question, take $f=$ the indicator function of some non-measurable subset $M$ of a set $N$ of measure $0,$ and $\Phi_n=0.$

Comment: What is the co-domain of $\Phi_n$ and $f$? If it is a general measurable space, the question is much more complicated.

Comment: I am thinking about real functions. And $A$ is the algebra generated by finite unions of sets of the form $(-\infty,a], (a,b], (a,\infty)$...

Comment: Thanks for the very clear counterexample @AnneBauval for the first part. I really appreciate your help.